# Can I manage transactions in the UI

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, orm, layers

Do I need an "application/service" layer to manage transactions if the domain layer only services the UI?

In other words, can't I just manage transactions in the UI when I have only one *consumer* of the domain layer?  In this case isn't the "application/service" layer just an un-needed extra layer of abstraction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, you are free to design the layers in your architecture however you want, but keep in mind transactions express some kind of business logic.

If you put business logic into the UI, you make it much harder to write automatic tests for it, since you restrict yourself to tests you can create with an UI testing tool. This typically means restrictions compared to tests you can write against the API of your service layer. For example, it is almost impossible to use a "test first" approach with a typical "UI robot". That is is a drawback you should not to underestimate when deciding against a service layer.

So if you are not interested in automatic tests, or the only kind of automatic tests are black box UI tests created by the QA team, then you won't need a service layer. But don't expect such a system to be easier to maintain.